# Colorbox/Drupal not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drupal, colorbox

I've got a new site up that uses Colorbox for image popups.  It works great in Firefox and Chrome but in IE nothing happens at all -- unless I hit F12 to turn on the Developer console, at which point it works.

http://www.mckinleywoodsapts.com/photo-gallery

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Almost certainly you have a console.log somewhere in the code. Do some searching.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean -- the problem is if I turn on developer console which gives me access to that in IE, the problem goes away so I can't debug properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution was to go back to the Lightbox2 module as that one works with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning colorbox to your elements in the correct way.  Remove the 'cboxElement' class for your link items (that should not be there, colorbox adds that class itself so that it knows the item has been setup correctly).  From there figure out why colorbox isn't been applied to your links with the '.colorbox' class.  I can't say exactly what the issue is with that as I don't understand all the Drupal stuff wrapped around it.

Comment: It must be a Drupal implementation issue since I'm not adding that class at all -- it's handled by Drupal's field display system.